# How CPU uses wider address bus than register size?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu, memory-hardware

i'm designing a CPU from scratch so i want it to be small. i decided to go with 4 bits registers. but 16 words of memory is a bit too small and i want more so i guess i need wider address bus (ie. 6). that raises a few questions:

1. how should i set address to memory address register?

   - using multiple data registers at the same time?
   - by having a dedicated 'construction-site address register), setting that address using multiple instructions and only then do jump?
2. how to read an address from an instruction? in my program i want to have instruction `jump 0x2E`. but i read my program word by word. i can't fit opcode and 6-bit operand in a 4 bit instruction. i can't do it even if my address bus is the same as data bus. how this problem is solved in practice?

Answer (score 0):

Look at early Intel processors designed under similar conditions, as 4004, 8008, 8051, 8080. In 8080, for example, 16-bit address is combined of register pairs like HL (so H+L), BC (B+C), DE (D+E), which also could be accessed separately (and there were few 16-bit operations, mainly for address handling).

In 8086, real address is combined of 16-bit segment shifted left by 4 bits plus 16-bit offset. Result is 20 bits.

In some successors of Mostek 6502, two special registers can specify high byte of address of "zero page" (memory operand for insrtructions with 1-byte address) and of stack.

To sum up, different designs from 1970s are all you need:)